# RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity triggered by onDestroy

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an exception every time I try to start a new activity.

```
 03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.elan_lifestyle/com.example.elan_lifestyle.Start}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3001)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:146)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5171)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1091)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPause(FragmentManager.java:1898)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPause(FragmentActivity.java:412)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at com.example.elan_lifestyle.Start.onPause(Start.java:172)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5314)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1226)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
    03-23 10:55:17.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29210):    ... 12 more
```

I've traced the problem to my onDestroy method:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try{
      btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();  // make sure the bluetooth is not searching
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("start: onDestroy","btAdapter crashed");
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

      Log.e("StartActivity","ending");  

    try{  
    unregisterReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver);    
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("StartActivity: onDestroy","reciever crashed");
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

  }
```

If I call onDestroy just after starting the new activity I get the exception and crash. If I don't call onDestroy it works fine but leaves the old activity still running. Here's the section of code where onDestroy is called:

```
            Intent i = new Intent(Start.this, Base.class);  // setup intent
            i.putExtra("Address", name);    // add the target device name to the intent           
            Start.this.startActivity(i);    // start main activity
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);    //override animation
            onDestroy();
```

What is causing this Exception and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of calling `onDestroy()` (which you shouldn't ever invoke by yourself at the first place), you should invoke `finish()` to destroy your running activity instance.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Classic case of poor programming on my part, can't believe I missed that.